# How do I save data from old 2 old iPhones then transfer data from one to the other?

Tags: iphone

My wife has an iPhone 3, 8GB, that is slowly dying. My mother (who is dead) left me her iPhone, a 16GB 3GS.

How do I:

1. Keep all the information from the phones. My mother's phone especially has sentimental value?
2. Wipe the 3GS?
3. Transfer everything from the 3 to the 3GS?

We don't care if the phone is jail-broken or not (they are not at the moment). Both phones are on the same provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iTunes can back up everything except for data that came from a computer.

That means apps not authorized on your iTunes, music from a computer and pictures not taken on the device (stored in the camera roll) are **not backed up**. Assuming you don't need to recover that information, just back up the devices and archive the iTunes backup folders so you can re-load those backups on another comparable device from a PC or a Mac.

Read up on the details here:

- [iPhone and iPod touch: About backups](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1766)

Once you've got a sure backup (I'd get a loaner phone from a friend to check the restore to see that you are happy before erasing any of the devices), you can then restore the "wife" backup onto the "mom" phone.

Answer (score -1):

You may try the "restore and backup" function on iTunes.Made a bakup for your iPhone 3 first and then restore your iPhone 3gs from the iPhone 3' backup files.

How to back up
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1766

How to restore
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1414

Comment: Restoring will wipe the content of the device getting restored.